# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const' for testing.es5.js

Tags: angular

I've switched to **Angular4.0.0-rc.1** and
it looks like ES5 testing bundles contain ES2015 code.

I'm getting this error:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
    at webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:10:0 <- src/test.ts:16345
```

Also found [related issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14730) on Angular repo.

Comment: Are you using angular cli ? If so, which version ?

Comment: @angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
node: 6.9.4
os: darwin x64

Answer (score 5):

I just created a basic Angular project and had the same (or similar) issue with PhantomJS integration.

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
  at webpack:///src/app/app.component.ts:1:0 <- src/test.ts:63184
```

### Our team got it to work and here's what we tossed in our documentation:

PhantomJS is a headless (aka, no GUI) browser that can be used for automated testing.
Currently, PhantomJS has a limitation in that it only supports the [ES5 standard](https://benmccormick.org/2015/09/14/es5-es6-es2016-es-next-whats-going-on-with-javascript-versioning/).

1. `npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt`
2. `npm install --save-dev karma-phantomjs-launcher`

   - in karma.conf.js

     1. add `require('karma-phantomjs-launcher')` to the plugins section
     2. add `PhantomJS` to the browsers
3. `npm install --save intl`

   - in src/polyfill.ts

     1. add `import 'intl';` *(uncomment at the bottom)*
     2. add `import "core-js/client/shim";` to the Evergreen requirements section
4. In src/tsconfig.spec.json (or whatever typescript config is used for tests)

   - Set the target to `es5`.

Assuming all goes well, testing should work.

Some examples on how to trigger a test run:

- `ng test --browsers PhantomJS --singleRun true`
- `./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start ./karma.conf.js  --browsers PhantomJS --singleRun true`

Comment: I have tried every possible solution to fix this and still get the error.

Comment: Since I responded over 2 years ago, I'm guessing its a different issue with a newer version of AngularJS. (This was based on 4.0.0-rc.1)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, tests were failing after updating karma.config.js to use PhantomJS launcher.

To sort the issue, updated **src/tsconfig.spec.json** to use ES5 instead of ES6.

```
{
    ...
    "target": "es5",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're using `@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1` I think you have a `tsconfig.json` looking like that :

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

And you should also have a `tsconfig.e2e.json` in your E2E folder :

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc-e2e",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "types":[
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

Simply remove the line `"target": "es6"` and as this files extends the previous one, you'll end up compiling your app in ES5.

It should work after that.

Answer (score 0):

And in my case it was due to a rogue import that webpack didn't like too much, or rather didn't know how to do deal with it:

```
import {HttpClient} from "selenium-webdriver/http";
```

Replacing with the correct HttpClient (our own) solved the issue. The issue was that the JS file was actually referring to the "const" keyword, however I believe that is an ES6 reserved word and not a ES5 reserved one, hence our error. 
If you get something similar, then you are referring to library where the down compiler hasn't spotted that you want any conversion.