# PhantomJS does not work with Karma in Angular2 project

Tags: angular, typescript, phantomjs, teamcity, karma-runner

I have created an out-of-the box project with the angular cli (1.0.0-rc1.0.0). Then I installed the PhantomJS plugin (*npm install karma-phantonjs-launcher*).
Reproduction steps:

1. create project with angular2 cli (*ng new TestPhantomJS*)
2. run *npm install karma-phantonjs-launcher*
3. in the karma.conf file add PhantomJS, ie change to `browsers:
   ['Chrome']` this `browsers:['Chrome', 'PhantomJS']`

Reason beeing that for Team City integration I need a headless browser.
The test run OK with *ng test* as long as the Chrome is specified as the browser,
The problem is when you try and use PhantomJS. You will get the error as per image below. My research suggests that this is has to do with PhantomJS and javascript version compatibility. However, I have not found a solution to this problem.

Has anyone else come across this and possibly found a solution?

[image]

My karma.conf

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
              : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: [ 'PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

My test.ts

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

// Unfortunately there's no typing for the `__karma__` variable. Just declare it as any.
declare var __karma__: any;
declare var require: any;

// Prevent Karma from running prematurely.
__karma__.loaded = function () {};

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
// Finally, start Karma to run the tests.
__karma__.start()
```

;

Comment: Can you show us your `karma.conf.js` and `test.ts` files? We're using PhantomJS and although we've run into problems before it is currently working.

Comment: @shusson , I have added my karma.conf and test.ts . Apart from the edit described above these are created "as is" by the angular cli.

Comment: try to import `polyfills.ts` in `test.ts` and `main.ts` ie `import './polyfills.ts';` and remove it from your `.angular-cli.json`

Comment: afaik, you're right, this is caused because the phantomjs doesn't support ecmascript 2015. so, stay using chrome until phantomjs 2.5 released i guess?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In fact, you don't have to wait for phantomjs 2.5 release.

- `npm install --save-dev karma-phantomjs-launcher`
- in *karma.conf.js*

  - add `require('karma-phantomjs-launcher')` to the plugins section
  - add *PhantomJS* to the browsers
- `npm install --save intl`
- in *src/polyfill.ts*

  - add `import 'intl';` (uncomment at the bottom)
  - add `import "core-js/client/shim";` to the Evergreen requirements section
- In *src/tsconfig.spec.json* set the target to es5.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42539894/7683428

Comment: Trying to follow your steps. Where exactly do you have to add the line import "core-js/client/shim"; ? Not entirely sure what you mean by Evergreen section ??

Comment: In  `BROWSER POLYFILLS` section, just after `// import 'core-js/es6/set';`

Comment: Thanks for this, works great!  The `core-js/client/shim` was what I was missing

Answer (score 15):

Since Chrome supports now (as of version 59) headless running, there's no reason any more to use outdated PhantomJS. Unless you cannot update/install chrome on target machine.
If you have included `karma-chrome-launcher` in karma.conf you can now just specify:

```
browsers: ['ChromeHeadless']
```

There's also possibility to use the [Canary edition](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) via `ChromeCanary` or `ChromeCanaryHeadless`.

Answer (score 2):

My current work around is to target es5 for the tests only.

**tsconfig.spec.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "target": "es5",
        ...
}
```

**.angular-cli.json**

```
{
    "project": {
        "name": "client"
    },
    "apps": [
        {
            ...
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            ...
```