# phantomJS for Angular 4

Tags: angular, phantomjs

I am keen on getting my project set up with gitlab's CI/CD. I tried to get phantomJS testing set up before moving it there:

1. I ran `npm i -D phantomjs-prebuilt karma-phantomjs-launcher` in my existing ng project.
2. I ran `npm i -s intl`
3. I edited my *karma.conf.js* file, to include:

   ```
     require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
   //...
     browsers: ['Chrome', 'PhantonJS'],
   ```
4. I edited the *polyfills.js* file, uncommenting:

   ```
   import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
   import 'core-js/es6/object';
   import 'core-js/es6/function';
   import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';  
   import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
   import 'core-js/es6/number';
   import 'core-js/es6/math';
   import 'core-js/es6/string';
   import 'core-js/es6/date';
   import 'core-js/es6/array';
   import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
   import 'core-js/es6/map';
   import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
   import 'core-js/es6/set';
   //...
   import 'intl';  // Run `npm install --save intl`.
   /**
    * Need to import at least one locale-data with intl.
    */
   import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
   ```

Now, I should be set to go with my tests... or so I thought. But I am getting:

### `ng test --browser PhantomJS --watch false`

```
27 07 2017 17:36:52.088:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket dyKzQygLaKO5BjSRAAAA with id 32293
707
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Use of reserved word 'let' in strict mode
  at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js:663
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Use of reserved word 'let' in strict mode
  at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js:663

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Use of reserved word 'let' in strict mode
  at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js:663
```

Answer (score 1):

It indeed has to do with PhantomJS not supporting ES2015. However, you don't have to wait for PhantomJS 2.5: you only need to install and configure the appropriate polyfills.

By following the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42692195/1501787 you will get PhantomJS running with ES2015 without problems. I have tested in an Angular 4 application and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You should check Your `tsconfig.json` if You are using `target: "es5"`

PhantomJS doesn't understand ES2015 yet and a `let` keyword is a part of this specification. PhantomJS Team [plans to release](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/milestone/16) support for ES2015 in version 2.5.