# Angular CLI unit tests with PhantomJS - Unexpected token 'const'

Tags: phantomjs, angular-cli

**Environment**

- @angular/cli@1.0.0

  - karma-phantomjs-launcher@1.0.4
- node@6.9.4
- npm@3.10.10

**Issue**
I've just added a service to my project which imports a function from a node_module library. Now, when I try to run my tests I get the following output.

```
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
  at webpack:///~/print.js/src/js/print.js:4:0 <- src/test.ts:21436
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
  at webpack:///~/print.js/src/js/print.js:4:0 <- src/test.ts:21436
```

A sample service looks like this

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import printjs from 'print.js/src';

    @Injectable()
    export class PrintService {
      constructor() {}

      testPrint(url: string): void {
        printjs(url);
      }
    }
```

I get this issue when I run

```
ng test --browsers PhantomJS
```

My tsconfig.json and src/tsconfig.spec.json have the target set to 'es5' which seems to be the most common cause of this issue.

I have read a number of posts including the following but haven't found anything that has worked. Is there anything else I can do?

- [SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const' for testing.es5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513591/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-const-for-testing-es5-js)
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5185

Comment: I know this question is 6 months old, but I ran into a very similar problem (I don't use CLI but webpack and get the very same error than you).

Did you figure out a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Having same issue also read many post but no luck ! 
Then i use `babel`. it take your code and make it compatible to your browser.

This link may help...
[click here](https://zirho.github.io/2016/06/06/karma-es6/)